# How to efficiently convert a Newton polynomial to its power form

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have been recently learning about polynomials and ways of presenting them and I have encountered a problem, which is converting a Newton polynomial to the power form in the **efficient** way.

Newton polynomial is expressed as 
$$w = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j)$$
where $a_i$ are coefficients of Newton polynomial and $x_j$ are given $x$ coordinates from points $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_{i-1}, y_{y-1})$. Power form is expressed as:
$$w = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$$

If we wanted to go from Newton's form to power form, we would have to rewrite the polynomial in its expanded form, so 
$w = a_0 + a_1 (x-x_0) + \dots + a_n (x-x_0)(x-x_1) \dots (x - x_{n-1})$ and then use all the data we have to complete calculations. The problem is that doing it by hand is pretty slow process, especially for higher-degree polynomials (even $\Pi_4$ would take a while).

My question is how to get power form from Newton polynomial and what time complexity does that algorithm have in big $\mathcal{O}$ notation?

Comment: You would use the Newton-Horner form of that expression, $$a_0+(x-x_0)\Bigl(a_1+(x-x_1)\Bigl(a_2+...\Bigl(a_{n-1}+(x-x_{n-1})a_n\Bigr)...\Bigr)\Bigr)$$ and the associated operations count for multiplications of a scalar factor.

Comment: Am I right that for the expanded form (from my question) the time complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and the form you have wrote is just $\mathcal{O}(n)$? What if we wanted to go from power form to Newton polynomial - is the algorithm also connected with that form or is it a bit more complex?

Comment: This would be true for the evaluation. For the computation of the coefficients, the exponent is one higher for both, assuming a "naive" implementation of your first formula. If you re-use the partial products, both variants will be $O(n^2)$, with a smaller constant in the Horner case, with a ratio of 1/2 or 1/3.